# How to conform a typed Array to a protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift2, protocols

```
protocol MyProtocol {}

func foo<Item: MyProtocol>(item: Item) {
    //...
}
```

I have a function `foo` that takes an item conforming to the `MyProtocol` protocol. Now I want the function also to accept arrays of items conforming to `MyProtocol`. Is it possible to make `Array<MyProtocol>` itself conform to `MyProtocol`?

Comment: Technically any type can conform to any protocol if it is needed. But what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `foo` method take an array as a parameter. That should do it.

```
func foo<Item: MyProtocol>(items: [Item]) {
}
```

Comment: I am making a two dimensional generic collection view, so cells within cells could be horizontally scrollable. Ideally I would want to reuse everything for both sequences and single instances of a type.

In reality `foo` would be something like `func configure<Item:Collectable>(cell: UICollectionViewCell, item: Item)`

Comment: Then it would look like `func configure<Item:Collectable>(cell: UICollectionViewCell, items: [Item])`.